# Lie bracket in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, lie-algebra

I am asking for a very simple, sketched out explanation of something I just learned today but I don't have the mathematical or physics background to make sure that at least I got the intuition or the idea correct.

It is my understanding that when using local coordinates on a manifold the Lie bracket vanishes.

At the same time, the curvature of spacetime has to do with the Lie bracket, and spacetime is curved.

Is the coordinate system in spacetime in GR a general local frame (how can this be possible (?)), or is it local (vanishing Lie bracket (?))? For the terms used here, please check [this short answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4462541/994433).

Comment: what does your textbook (or other textbooks) say?

Comment: This helps: https://youtu.be/oYJfjW5wFu8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the same time, the curvature of spacetime has to do with the Lie bracket

It does not. If you have two vector fields $V$ and $W$, you can define new vector field $X\equiv[V,W]$ such that for every function $f$ on the manifold it satisfies $$X(f)\equiv[V,W](f)\equiv V(W(f)) - W(V(f)).$$
The curvature is present nowhere in the definition.

> Is the coordinate system in spacetime in GR a general local frame?

Quoting from the answer you provided

> In fact, this is a necessary and sufficient condition : if $\mathbf e_i$ is a frame whose Lie brackets vanish, then there are local coordinates $x^i$ such that $\mathbf e_i = \partial_i$.

So yes it is. Or more correctly (your statement has a category error), local coordinate system gives rise to a local coordinate vector fields which is a special case of general local frame for which Lie brackets vanish.

Again all of this has nothing to do with any curvature, you do not even need metric to be defined for these statements.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Lie bracket *of the basis vectors* vanishes.  In a coordinate chart $x$, the partial derivative operators $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right\}$ constitute a basis for the tangent bundle.  Each $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is a vector field, and the Lie bracket between any two such vector fields vanishes:
$$\forall f \in C^\infty \ : \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right]f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i} = 0 \implies \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right]=0\tag{$\star$}$$

This is due to the familiar symmetry of mixed partial derivatives from elementary analysis.  However, this certainly doesn't mean that the Lie bracket *always* vanishes.  For example, on $\mathbb R^2$ with coordinates $(x,y)$, we have that $\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right]=0$ as always but e.g.

$$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \neq 0$$
as can be easily checked by applying the commutator to a test function as in $(\star)$.

> Is the coordinate system in spacetime in GR a general local frame (how can this be possible (?)), or is it local (vanishing Lie bracket (?))?

A coordinate system induces a *specific type* of local frame, called a *holonomic frame*. In such a frame, the basis vector fields are given by partial derivative operators with respect to the corresponding coordinates, and the Lie brackets between those vector fields vanish as demonstrated above.  On the other hand, a *general* frame $\{\hat e_i\}$ cannot be written as partial derivative operators, and therefore the Lie brackets $[\hat e_i,\hat e_j]\neq 0$ in general.

Comment: Thank you. So, for example, in the case of polar coordinates in 2D, or a sphere embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, wouldn't we be talking about a general frame? And wouldn't the basis vectors at a point be the partial derivatives of the positional vector? In such cases, would the Lie bracket vanish?

Comment: ... I am asking because the last sentence in your answer confuses me. Thanks again for your very didactic post.

Comment: @JAP The word *general* just means *non-specific*.  On an $n$-dimensional manifold, any set of $n$ vector fields which are non-vanishing and linearly independent at each point can be used as a basis.  This set is called a [vielbein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism), and is what is meant when you say a "general frame," where *general* again means *not special*.  The kind of vielbein which arises from the partial derivatives in some coordinate system is a *special* kind of vielbein which has the property that the Lie bracket of any two vectors in the vielbein vanishes, but [...]

Comment: [...] this isn't true for vielbeins which do not arise in this way.  In 2D polar coordinates, both the sets $\{\partial_r, \partial_\theta\}$ and $\{\partial_r,r\partial_\theta\} \equiv \{\hat r,\hat \theta\}$ constitute perfectly acceptable vielbeins. However, the former is a holonomic basis because it is the partial derivatives of a coordinate system, while the latter is not. The Lie bracket of the former vanishes, while the Lie bracket of the latter is equal to $\partial_\theta$.

Comment: Very interesting. And in GR I presume that there are a number of vielbeins might have been considered, and some of them are based on partial derivatives (i.e. "special"), and vanish, while others are not?

Comment: Yes. As SolubleFish mentioned in their answer, the pairwise Lie brackets $[\hat e_i,\hat e_j]$ vanish if and only if there is a coordinate system $x$ such that $\hat e_i = \partial/\partial x^i$.